# What causes website to be not found with valid SSL certs from letsencrypt in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, lets-encrypt

I am using AKS and azure dns. I have added a clusterIssuer and Ingress and I can access my website at its URL using `http`. Having created the clusterIssuer and Ingress i checked the logs using `kubtctl describe certificate`, `kubectl describe certificaterequest`, `kubectl describe order`, `kubectl describe challenge` ... Everything looks good, there are no errors and it tells in the certificate request command that the certificate was issued successfully. However when I try and vist my website url at `https` it just hangs until I get a response form the web browser.

> The page isn't responding

What causes this? How can this be fixed?

Here is the ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-website-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "www.mywebsite.io"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gmrfe
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
#        - "mywebsite.io"
        - "www.mywebsite.io"
      secretName: my-website-secret
```

Here is the clusterissuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: danielptm@me.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: my-website-secret
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
#        selector:
#          matchLabels:
#            "use-http01-solver": "true"
```

Here is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gmrfe
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gmrfe
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gmrfe
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gmrfe
          image: <my-aks-repo>:gmrfe_latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tls
              mountPath: /etc/tls
              readOnly: true
          env:
            - name: TLS_CERT
              value: /etc/tls/tls.crt
            - name: TLS_KEY
              value: /etc/tls/tls.key
      volumes:
        - name: tls
          secret:
            secretName: my-website-secret
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gmrfe
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: MC_aks-rg_dpt-aks_westus
    # See the az_scripts/create_static_ip.bash script for how to create this
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-pip-name: myIp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: gmrfe
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Don't you also need to expose port 443?  That said,  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  This looks more like a configuration question.

Comment: I was going through your yaml, and I have few recommendation, kindly try once and let me know- Your ingress Includes the cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: "true" annotation. This is typically used to issue a temporary certificate while the actual certificate from Let's Encrypt is being obtained.
The tls section comments out mywebsite.io. If you also want to serve traffic for -mywebsite.io, this should be uncommented. My suggestion is not to include the cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: "true" annotation. This isn't strictly necessary once you have a valid certificate.

Comment: Your deployment yaml includes volume mounts for tls, with environment variables TLS_CERT and TLS_KEY.
This setup implies that the application is configured to use these certificates directly, which isn't necessary if TLS termination is handled at the Ingress level. Since the Ingress is handling TLS termination, the application container doesn't need to deal with TLS certificates directly. Nginx Ingress controller for TLS termination usually don't need to expose port 443 in your Deployment or Service. Instead, the Ingress controller itself is responsible for handling HTTPS traffic.